# Configuring grunt-uncss with Yeoman's generator-webapp

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, sass, gruntjs, yeoman

I am trying to configure grunt-uncss with a Sass Bootstrap scaffold made with Yeoman's generator-webapp. I've found this discussion that comes close to what I'm trying to do: https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss/issues/75

I tried to change and apply this to my situation but Grunt is giving me the following error:

```
...
Running "uncss:dist" (uncss) task
File .tmp/styles/main.css created: 121.77 kB → 7.24 kB

Running "cssmin:dist" (cssmin) task
File dist/styles/main.css created: 7.24 kB → 4.8 kB

Running "cssmin:generated" (cssmin) task
>> Destination not written because minified CSS was empty.
File dist/styles/main.css created: 121.77 kB → 96.74 kB
...
```

Gruntfile.js

```
// Generated on 2014-06-16 using generator-webapp 0.4.9
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

    // Load grunt tasks automatically
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);

    // Configurable paths
    var config = {
        app: 'app',
        dist: 'dist'
    };

    // Define the configuration for all the tasks
    grunt.initConfig({

        // Project settings
        config: config,

        // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
        watch: {
            bower: {
                files: ['bower.json'],
                tasks: ['bowerInstall']
            },
            js: {
                files: ['<%= config.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
                tasks: ['jshint'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            jstest: {
                files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
                tasks: ['test:watch']
            },
            gruntfile: {
                files: ['Gruntfile.js']
            },
            sass: {
                files: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
                tasks: ['sass:server', 'autoprefixer']
            },
            styles: {
                files: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
                tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
                },
                files: [
                    '<%= config.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
                    '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= config.app %>/images/{,*/}*'
                ]
            }
        },

        // The actual grunt server settings
        connect: {
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                open: true,
                livereload: 35729,
                // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
                hostname: '0.0.0.0'
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    middleware: function(connect) {
                        return [
                            connect.static('.tmp'),
                            connect().use('/bower_components', connect.static('./bower_components')),
                            connect.static(config.app)
                        ];
                    }
                }
            },
            test: {
                options: {
                    open: false,
                    port: 9001,
                    middleware: function(connect) {
                        return [
                            connect.static('.tmp'),
                            connect.static('test'),
                            connect().use('/bower_components', connect.static('./bower_components')),
                            connect.static(config.app)
                        ];
                    }
                }
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    base: '<%= config.dist %>',
                    livereload: false
                }
            }
        },

        // Empties folders to start fresh
        clean: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    dot: true,
                    src: [
                        '.tmp',
                        '<%= config.dist %>/*',
                        '!<%= config.dist %>/.git*'
                    ]
                }]
            },
            server: '.tmp'
        },

        // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
        jshint: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
                reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
            },
            all: [
                'Gruntfile.js',
                '<%= config.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                '!<%= config.app %>/scripts/vendor/*',
                'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
            ]
        },

        // Mocha testing framework configuration options
        mocha: {
            all: {
                options: {
                    run: true,
                    urls: ['http://<%= connect.test.options.hostname %>:<%= connect.test.options.port %>/index.html']
                }
            }
        },

        // Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
        sass: {
            options: {
                includePaths: [
                    'bower_components'
                ]
            },
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
                    src: ['*.scss'],
                    dest: '.tmp/styles',
                    ext: '.css'
                }]
            },
            server: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
                    src: ['*.scss'],
                    dest: '.tmp/styles',
                    ext: '.css'
                }]
            }
        },

        // Add vendor prefixed styles
        autoprefixer: {
            options: {
                browsers: ['last 1 version']
            },
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
                    src: '{,*/}*.css',
                    dest: '.tmp/styles/'
                }]
            }
        },

        // Automatically inject Bower components into the HTML file
        bowerInstall: {
            app: {
                src: ['<%= config.app %>/index.html'],
                exclude: ['bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js']
            },
            sass: {
                src: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}']
            }
        },

        // Renames files for browser caching purposes
        rev: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    src: [
                        '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                        '<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                        '<%= config.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.*',
                        '<%= config.dist %>/styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
                        '<%= config.dist %>/*.{ico,png}'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },

        // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
        // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
        // additional tasks can operate on them
        useminPrepare: {
            options: {
                dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
            },
            html: '<%= config.app %>/index.html'
        },

        // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
        usemin: {
            options: {
                assetsDirs: ['<%= config.dist %>', '<%= config.dist %>/images']
            },
            html: ['<%= config.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
            css: ['<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css']
        },

        // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
        imagemin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.app %>/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png}',
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>/images'
                }]
            }
        },

        svgmin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.app %>/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>/images'
                }]
            }
        },

        htmlmin: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                    collapseWhitespace: true,
                    removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                    removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                    removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                    removeOptionalTags: true,
                    removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                    useShortDoctype: true
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.dist %>',
                    src: '{,*/}*.html',
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
                }]
            }
        },

        // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
        // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
        // to use the Usemin blocks.
        // cssmin: {
        //     dist: {
        //         files: {
        //             '<%= config.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
        //                 '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
        //                 '<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
        //             ]
        //         }
        //     }
        // },
        // uglify: {
        //     dist: {
        //         files: {
        //             '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
        //                 '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
        //             ]
        //         }
        //     }
        // },
        // concat: {
        //     dist: {}
        // },

        // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
        copy: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.app %>',
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>',
                    src: [
                        '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                        '.htaccess',
                        'images/{,*/}*.webp',
                        '{,*/}*.html',
                        'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
                    ]
                }, {
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    cwd: '.',
                    src: ['bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/fonts/bootstrap/*.*'],
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
                }]
            },
            styles: {
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
                dest: '.tmp/styles/',
                src: '{,*/}*.css'
            }
        },

        // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up build process
        concurrent: {
            server: [
                'sass:server',
                'copy:styles'
            ],
            test: [
                'copy:styles'
            ],
            dist: [
                'sass',
                'copy:styles',
                'imagemin',
                'svgmin'
            ]
        },

        autoshot: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    path: 'screenshots/',
                    remote : {
                        files: [
                            { src: 'http://localhost:<%= connect.options.port %>', dest: 'app.jpg'}
                        ]
                    },
                    viewport: ['320x480','480x320','384x640','640x384','602x963','963x602','600x960','960x600','800x1280','1280x800','768x1024','1024x768']
                }
            }
        },

        uncss: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    stylesheets: ['../.tmp/styles/main.css']
                },
                files: {
                    '.tmp/styles/main.css': ['app/index.html']
                }
            }
        }
    });


    grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
        if (target === 'dist') {
            return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'concurrent:server',
            'autoprefixer',
            'connect:livereload',
            'watch'
        ]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
        grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
        grunt.task.run([target ? ('serve:' + target) : 'serve']);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('test', function (target) {
        if (target !== 'watch') {
            grunt.task.run([
                'clean:server',
                'concurrent:test',
                'autoprefixer'
            ]);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
            'connect:test',
            'mocha'
        ]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean:dist',
        'useminPrepare',
        'concurrent:dist',
        'autoprefixer',
        'concat',
        'uncss',
        'cssmin',
        'uglify',
        'copy:dist',
        'rev',
        'usemin',
        'htmlmin'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'newer:jshint',
        'test',
        'build'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('screenshots', [
        'clean:server',
        'concurrent:server',
        'connect:livereload',
        'autoshot'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('build-uncss', [
        'build',
        'uncss'
    ]);
};
```

I understand it's an issue with the order of events for all the grunt tasks ran with "grunt", but I can't find the point that breaks the process. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

For this particular situation, changing:

```
files: { '.tmp/styles/main.css': ['app/index.html'] }
```

to...

```
files: { '.tmp/concat/styles/main.css': ['app/index.html'] }
```

after adding `tmp: '.tmp'` to `var config = {...}`

```
var config = {
        app: 'app',
        dist: 'dist',
        tmp: '.tmp'
};
```

fixes the issue.

The "dist" now folder contains a minified, revisioned and uncss'd stylesheet. Just what I needed.

Comment: Hi @user2105528, it doesn't solve for me. Can you provide a working repository please? The dist folder contains a minified but not uncss-ed file. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this question while trying to resolve the same issue. In case anyone else is still facing this, the usemin block in your index.html overrides the cssmin grunt task, i.e.

```
<!-- build:css({.tmp,client}) styles/main.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" media="all" type='text/css'>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Remove the "build" comments, leaving:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" media="all" type='text/css'>
```

And configure the cssmin task in your Gruntfile.js. For me I also had to rewrite my concat task due to multiple stylesheets.

My sample:

```
cssmin: {
  generated: {
    files: {
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
        '.tmp/concat/styles/{,*/}*.css'
      ]
    }
  }
},
concat: {
  css: {
    files: {
      '.tmp/concat/styles/main.css': ['.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css']
    }
  }
},
uncss: {
  dist: {
    files: {
      '.tmp/concat/styles/main.css': ['<%= yeoman.app %>/*.html', '<%= yeoman.app %>/views/**/*.html']
    },
    options: {
      stylesheets: ['../.tmp/concat/styles/main.css']
    }
  }
}
```

If you only have one main.css, leave out the 'concat' task and concat prefixes for file paths.

The build task:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', [
  'clean:dist',
  'wiredep',
  'useminPrepare',
  'concurrent:dist',
  'autoprefixer',
  'concat',
  'ngAnnotate',
  'copy:dist',
  'cdnify',
  'uncss',
  'cssmin',
  'uglify',
  'filerev',
  'usemin',
  'htmlmin'
]);
```

Not sure if it's the best way, hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score -1):

Addy Osmani, author of the grunt-uncss plugin, has written a yeoman generator incorporating the plugin.

```
$ yo webapp-uncss
```

https://github.com/addyosmani/generator-webapp-uncss

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The OP stated, "I am trying to configure grunt-uncss with a Sass Bootstrap scaffold made with Yeoman's generator-webapp."

The command configures grunt-uncss in a Yeoman webapp. Adding Sass and Bootstrap are options in the setup.

The link is the reference.